# What is the Correct "Feature" to use for TYPE_WIFI in ConnectivityManager?

Tags: android, wifi, android-networking

I need to use the ConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(...) method in android , and What feature Do i need to pass as second param if i pass TYPE_WIFI as first param?

Answer (score -1):

Here they are:

```
// "Features" accessible through the connectivity manager
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS = "enableMMS";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_SUPL = "enableSUPL";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_DUN = "enableDUN";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_HIPRI = "enableHIPRI";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_DUN_ALWAYS = "enableDUNAlways";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_FOTA = "enableFOTA";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_IMS = "enableIMS";
static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_CBS = "enableCBS";
```

Taken from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/Phone.java)